# Is there limit on size of GeoJSON files that can be handled by QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson, file-size

I'm trying to load a GeoJSON file with about 5K features in QGIS, and it fails, saying `Invalid Data Source` without further details. If I remove features down to 1K, it works. Is there a limit on the size of GeoJSON files that can be handled by QGIS? How can I understand what's going on?

I'm using QGIS version 2.8.2-Wien on Mac.

Comment: I can't shed light on this, but I'm currently looking at a GeoJSON feature collection of point geometries with lots of attributes... and there are > 18,000 points. Are you using a [Feature Collection Object](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects)?

Comment: There might be an invalid geometry (or mixed geometry) in the 4k feautures you deleted. If you split the data into 5 files with 1K, do you get all features?

Comment: My bad. It was just a `NaN` instead of `NULL` that wasn't recognized by ogr. Problem solved.